# How to remove pagination numbers

Tags: javascript, pagination

I'm trying to completely remove the 'page' numbers at the bottom of the listJS pagination [here](http://www.listjs.com/docs/plugins/pagination) with the full code example [here](http://codepen.io/javve/pen/bBfgD). My attempt is that other than the 3 starting valueNames displayed, all others can only be found by inputting the relevant text, not scrolling pages.

I've attempted to set the inner and outer window values to 0, but either that isn't the solution or I've not configured it correctly. As you'll tell my expertise is limited! If someone could help that'd be great.

```
var monkeyList = new List('test-list', {
valueNames: ['name'],
page: 3,
innerWindow: 0,
outerWindow: 0,
plugins: [ ListPagination({}) ] 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just hide the pagination - add the following css

```
.pagination{
  display:none
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOKOJO

Comment: Well that was simple and rather obvious. Thank you!